# How to make an aggregation map in Dash (by plot.ly)

Tags: mapbox, dashboard, plotly-dash

I discovered recently plotly [Dash](https://plot.ly/dash/) and I am wondering if it's possible to do an [aggregation map](http://wiki.gis.com/wiki/index.php/Aggregation) with it. In my understanding, the only map function is scattermapbox which does not allow such a thing. Am I wrong? If no, is there another way to do it? Maybe another framework? I'm mainly interested in doing a web app which presents side by side an aggregation map and a data grid (datatable in Dash) which interact with each other.

See [here](https://blog.framer.com/how-to-use-framer-mapbox-rapidly-prototyping-map-cluster-21d9d5487026) for an example of an aggregation map (or map cluster).

Comment: Did you check out all the plots here: https://plot.ly/python/? There are also these aggregation transformers: https://plot.ly/python/aggregations/, not sure if they fit your need. I find it hard to find something specific for you because your question is a bit vague for me.

Comment: Thanks Philipp for your help. I edited my question to add example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of version 4.1.1 we support the new `densitymapbox` trace type, which does something quite similar: https://plot.ly/python/mapbox-density-heatmaps/

Comment: And is it also possible to use it with Dash?

Comment: Yes, all Plotly.py features are compatible with Dash automatically!

Comment: @nicolaskruchten Its aggregation method seems to be the sum though. Can it be changed to average? I can imagine a lot of applications where this would be needed. e.g. temperatures or signal strengths.